# Polynomial equations with 3 unknown real numbers

Tags: polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Please help with this one. The previous version had a mistake. 
Let $x, y,z$ be real numbers and $z=\frac{2xy-2}{zx-1}=\frac{y-2}{y^2-2x}=\frac{xy^2+2-x}{2y}$. Find all sets of ${x, y, z}$ 
 ---- 
Thank you for help.

Comment: Did you attempt the problem?

Comment: I tried, but the operations were made mostly by random and led to nothing.

Comment: no $x,y,z$ real numbers satisfy your equations.

Comment: you can eliminate the variables step by step

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Comment: one Moment please i'm computing....

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait.

Comment: are you sure that you have made no typo? my equation in $x$ is complicated

Comment: I've checked a few times.

Comment: could it be that your System has only complex solutions?

Comment: They should be real

Comment: ok i will Control my solution again

Comment: I think the answer should be dependency of x, y, z

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I obtain the same as you, I think. I am sure there is a typo in the formula.

Comment: My bad. There was a mistake. Could you help me now?

Answer (score 0):

Substituting 
$$
z=\frac{y-2}{y^2-2x}
$$
we obtain two equations in $x$ and $y$, where we can take its resultant. This is given by
$$
2y^{10} - y^9 + 16y^8 - 3y^7 + 20y^6 - 35y^5 + 32y^4 - 257y
^3 + 154y^2 + 288y + 128=0,
$$
which has exactly $10$ complex, non-real solutions. Then $x$ is given by  a polynomial in $y$, namely by
$$
x=( - 8y^9 + 6y^8 - 61y^7 + 16y^6 - 66y^5 + 134y^4 - 193y^3 + 1308y^2 -
628y - 1184)/576.
$$

Comment: yes this is also equivalent to my equation

Comment: My bad. There was a mistake. Could you help me now

Comment: With the new equation there is a real solution, $y=0.461762962568$, and $x=(2y^4 + 3y^3 + 14y^2 + 13y + 24)/16$. The way of solution is the same. Eliminate $z$ and $x$.